# Embedding current location ( longitude and latitude ) in the Google Places API

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-places-api, currentlocation

I am trying to integrate Google Places API into my iOS app. I am referring to this blog :
http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/07/working-with-google-places-api.html

Now I am finding out my current location of the iPhone, how do I embed the longitude and latitude which I have got into the following URL instead of "location=34.0522222,-118.2427778" :

```
#define PlacesURL @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=restaurants&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key"
```

So that I get the restaurants locations near my current location and not near the hard coded location given in the code.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLLocation *location = [[AppHelper appDelegate] mLatestLocation];//custom code to get latestPosition of user


NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&types=restaurants&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key"
,location.coordinate.longitude,location.coordinate.latitude]];
```

Comment: i got this now the problem is how  and where to define  [location.coordinate.longitude,location.coordinate.latitude]